# RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent not working on android 13

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

when i try to open file after download everything works fine on iOS and android 12 but when i run app on android 13 this command doesn’t run. I have added all the permissions and also configure this library by following each [steps](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-installation). My react-native version is 0.70.6

i was trying to open a file but it is not opening in android 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add this to the manifest?

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```